# passing CoreData from UITableViewCell to viewcontroller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data, viewcontroller

I'm trying to create the feature where when a user clicks on a specific cell in my UITableView, the Project will segue to a new ViewController and show all the information that has been saved in the CoreData. The Problem is that when I touch on a cell I get an error of

```
Unexpected nil while unwrapping optional value
```

Here is my code as it is right now within the ViewController that has the TableView

```
class ContactViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {
        var selectName:String?
    var selectPhone:String?
var selectComment:String?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectName = contact[indexPath.row].name
        selectPhone = contact[indexPath.row].phone
        selectComment = contact[indexPath.row].comments
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "MySegue"{
            if let destVC = segue.destination as? IndiViewController {
                destVC.NameLabel = selectName
                destVC.PhoneLabel = selectPhone
                destVC.CommentLabel = selectComment
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code in IndiViewController (the VC in which I want the user to view the contact)

```
class IndiViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var PhoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var CommentsLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

I've tried a few other methods but all still delivered the same error

I troubleshooted a bit to see which variable truly was causing the nil by doing this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "MySegue"{
            if let destVC = segue.destination as? IndiViewController {
                destVC.NameLabel = "selectName" //I thought if perhaps the nil was the var selectName this would at least let me know

            }
        }
```

However even through this, the app crashes and gives the same error. So I think the issue is with the Labels in the IndiViewController.

So I tried creating an empty String and assigning it to NameLabel like this:

```
class IndiViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!

var name = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
NameLabel.text = name
    }
}
```

but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your `NameLabel` outlet correctly linked to your StoryBoard?

Comment: @Olympiloutre yes, I even re-connected them just to be sure

Comment: if the `IndiViewController` fail itself without even passing datas to it, it strongly looks like an outlet reference which is wrong
try replacing `@IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!` with `@IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel?` 
Then in viewDidLoad `print( NameLabel )`

Comment: Thank you for the input, however it still crashes with the error `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key NameLabel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet it can be an IBOutlet error, even for typo.

1. delete `@IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!`
2. remove the link in the StoryBoard "referencing outlets" tab
3. click-drag a new outlet for the `UILabel` and **do not name it with a capital letter**

   `// @IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!

   @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!`

**Edit**

Also try to pass your informations in two times :

1. create a new var in your destinationViewController like :

   ```
   class IndiViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!

       var myText: String = ""

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           nameLabel.text = myText // assign the var to the labels text
       }
   ```

   }
2. In your prepareForSegue method assign `myText` and not the `nameLabel.text`

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "MySegue"{
           if let destVC = segue.destination as? IndiViewController {
               destVC.myText = "selectName" 
           }
       }
   }
   ```

my guess is that you cant acces IBOutlets in `prepare(for segue:)` method. The destination ViewController is not built yet

Comment: when I went through with this method I first attempted it like this `destVC.nameLabel?.text = selectName` and it didn't crash, however none of the labels were really changed, they all just said 'label'. Then, when I removed the `?` from the code such as `destVC.nameLabel.text = selectName` the app crashes claiming `Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @TariqKhan just edit my post, try this method. Not so sure you can access destination's Outlets in prepareForSegue method.

Comment: ahh yes this is exactly what I was missing! now it works. Thank you very much. I think the problem was that `nameLabel` needed to be initialized before hand. This did the trick

Comment: nice! Also try not to put outlet ( var in general ) in capitalized letter